# Populating a UiWebview control with data from a Kumulos API

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I am currently really new to Xcode and the whole Iphone App development but reasonable proficient in Javascript/HTML/SQL. 
I am looking at creating a new App which queries its data from a Kumulos database (Kumulos API's).
Before i head down the path, i just want to know if it was possible to query the database(i know how to do this), but more importantly load the returned data into a webview control.

Similar sort of idea as facebook app. I know they use a webview control.

Ive searched, but currently haven't found an answer on how do do this.

Can you suggest a better method?

Excuse my lack of coding examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is create objecive-C methods that are called by the javascript in your web view as per this guide:

[Calling Objective-C from UIWebView](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/)

This way you could call an objective-C function that returns the data loaded from Kumulos, you can then do what you like in the javascript with the loaded data.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the answer i was looking for.